# Variable return type with QVariant and templates

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I am trying to subclass `QStandardItemModel` in order to make sure whenever a `QStandardItem` of this `QStandardItemModel` is removed, that item's data is also deleted, which is in dynamically allocated memory. Below is an example:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType*)

MyType* myData = new MyType;
QStandardItem* myItem = new QStandardItem;
QVariant var;
var.setValue(myData);
myItem->setData(var);
```

Now when I remove `myItem` from the item model, I wanna make sure `myData` is also deleted. So I inherit from `QStandardItemModel` as follows:

```
// header file
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QModelIndex>


class TreeViewItemModel: public QStandardItemModel {

public:
    TreeViewItemModel(QTreeView* parent = 0) {}

    template <typename T> void delete_dynamic_item(QStandardItem* item,
        int role = Qt::DisplayRole);

    virtual ~TreeViewItemModel() {}

private:
    Q_OBJECT


};

// source file
#include "tree_view_item_model.h"

template <typename T>
void TreeViewItemModel::delete_dynamic_item(QStandardItem* item,
    int role) {

    int row = item->row();
    QModelIndex parentIndex = this->indexFromItem(item->parent());

    QVariant itemVariant = item->data(role);
    T itemData = itemVariant.value<T>();
    delete itemData;

    this->removeRow(row, parentIndex);

}
```

This compiles only when I do not call `TreeViewItemModel::delete_dynamic_item()` in my program. If I do, I get a linker error `LNK2019`. I searched the web and tried suggested things like:

```
T itemData = (T) itemVariant.value<void*>();
```

But they did not work for me. I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: "So I subclass QStandardItemModel as follows:" you are not subclassing  QStandardItemModel, you are just subclassing TreeViewItemModel, which will not affect QStandardItemModel.

Comment: Ooops... sorry, you are right. I fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have the template implementation in the .cpp file instead of the header .h file. Move the implementation to the header file. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/495056/1485885) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Yeah I was able to compile and run my program when I moved the implementation into the header as you and the other answer suggested. Strangely though, at some other point in my source code I was able to separate the template implementation and put it in a .cpp file and it still worked. Maybe I should read more about templates in c++. Thank you for your help.